# reactive shiny object type closure is not subsettable

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I cannot figure out why I am getting the below error on this chunk of code. I appreciate any thoughts in advance. thank you.

Warning: Error in $: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
Index_Percent <- reactive({input$IndexWeight})

TBA_Index_Data <- reactive({
  left_join(TBAData_Gathered,Index_Weights)

TBA_Index_Data$Index_Percentage[TBA_Index_Data$cusip == "Cash"] <- Index_Percent()

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you are providing, it seems you are trying to load a reactive function inside itself.

the correct form would be something like this:

```
Index_Percent <- reactive({input$IndexWeight})

TBA_Index_Data <- reactive({
  # these variables are reactive functions? if so, you need to add () as well.
  table <- left_join(TBAData_Gathered,Index_Weights) 
  table$Index_Percentage[table$cusip == "Cash"] <- Index_Percent()
  table
})
```

Comment: awha! thank you so much! appreciate the lightening fast response.

Comment: You're welcome. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.